# Problems to create dynamic reactive form with Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic form layout with Angular. I need to load form from this payload:

```
      [{
                    name: 'inputInstallment',
                    id: '3',
                    companyId: 1,
                    dropoffId: 2,
                    dropoffSectionId: 1,
                    priority: 2,
                    type: {
                      id: '2',
                      companyId: 1,
                      description: 'Input text',
                      __typename: 'DropoffQuestionType',
                    },
                    description: 'InputLabel',
                    answers: [],
                    options: [],
                    __typename: 'DropoffQuestion',
                  }]
```

Next step is create form.

```
    constructor(
    private _abandonmentService: AbandonmentService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  form: FormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({});
  createForm(questions: IDropoffQuestion[]) {
    for (const question of questions) {
      const validatorsToAdd = [];
      if (question.required) {
        validatorsToAdd.push(Validators.requiredTrue);
      }

      this.form.addControl(
        question.name,
        this._formBuilder.control('', validatorsToAdd)
      );
    }
  }
```

At HTML file:

```
            <ng-container
              *ngFor="let question of dropoffQuizzData.sections[0].questions"
            >
              <ng-container
                *ngIf="['Input text'].includes(question.type.description)"
              >
                <acp-form-field>
                  <acp-input
                    (acpChange)="
                      setQuestionValue($event, question.id, question.name)
                    "
                    placeholder="{{ question.description }}"
                    [formControlName]="question.name"
                    [name]="question.name"
                    [value]="question.value"
                  ></acp-input>
                  <acp-hint
                    type="feedback"
                    *ngIf="
                      form.controls[question.name].invalid &&
                      (form.controls[question.name].dirty ||
                        form.controls[question.name].touched)
                    "
                    >{{ question.hintMessage }}</acp-hint
                  >
                </acp-form-field>
              </ng-container>
             </ng-container>
```

When I send the form for validation, even after filling it out, the answer always returns `false`, as if the form was not filled out.

validation method:

```
  checkValidationsForm(formGroup: FormGroup | FormArray) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach((field) => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);
      control?.markAsDirty();
      control?.markAsTouched();
      console.log(control?.errors, field);
      if (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray) {
        this.checkValidationsForm(control);
      }
    });
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong?